# Dovecot doveadm backup occassionally failing with error 65 - how to handle

Tags: backup, dovecot

I'm trying to set up backups of dovecot emails between 2 servers.   The command doing the heavy lifting is:

```
 doveadm -D backup -R -u clientuser@example.com ssh MAINSERVER.IP doveadm dsync-server -u clientuser@example.com
```

For most users it works fine, but for a couple of users I am getting an error 65 or error 75.  (The script says remote command returned error 75..." but when I put this in a script the return code is 65.

The dovecot output for the failed account is as below:

```
Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_acl_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_acl_plugin.so: undefined symbol: acl_user_module (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_expire_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_expire_plugin.so: undefined symbol: expire_set_deinit (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_quota_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_quota_plugin.so: undefined symbol: quota_user_module (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib10_doveadm_sieve_plugin.so
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_fts_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/lib20_doveadm_fts_plugin.so: undefined symbol: fts_user_get_language_list (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
Debug: Skipping module doveadm_mail_crypt_plugin, because dlopen() failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/doveadm/libdoveadm_mail_crypt_plugin.so: undefined symbol: mail_crypt_box_get_pvt_digests (this is usually intentional, so just ignore this message)
doveadm(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: Effective uid=999, gid=999, home=/data/mail/clientsusername@example.com
doveadm(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/Maildir, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/Maildir, alt=
doveadm(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: Namespace : Using permissions from /data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/Maildir: mode=0700 gid=default
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Local mailbox tree: INBOX guid=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c uid_validity=1681441643 uid_next=2 subs=no last_change=0 last_subs=0
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Remote mailbox tree: INBOX guid=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c uid_validity=1396487587 uid_next=60912 subs=no last_change=0 last_subs=0
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Remote mailbox tree: Deleted Messages guid=c803c2075f1e625874120000b8a5d860 uid_validity=1396487588 uid_next=36883 subs=yes last_change=0 last_subs=1482825311
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Remote mailbox tree: Sent Messages guid=55567b0e54b57d58770d0000b8a5d860 uid_validity=1396487589 uid_next=345 subs=yes last_change=0 last_subs=1484633428
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Remote mailbox tree: Drafts guid=8e1b6a01ab197e602d700000b8a5d860 uid_validity=1396487591 uid_next=1 subs=yes last_change=0 last_subs=1618876837
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Remote mailbox tree: Notes guid=da8ed0191098355c672d0000b8a5d860 uid_validity=1396487590 uid_next=1 subs=yes last_change=0 last_subs=1547016208
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Mailbox Deleted Messages: local=00000000000000000000000000000000/0/0, remote=c803c2075f1e625874120000b8a5d860/0/1: mailbox not selectable yet
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Mailbox Drafts: local=00000000000000000000000000000000/0/0, remote=8e1b6a01ab197e602d700000b8a5d860/0/1: mailbox not selectable yet
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Mailbox INBOX: local=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c/0/1, remote=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c/0/1: Mailboxes are equal
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Mailbox Notes: local=00000000000000000000000000000000/0/0, remote=da8ed0191098355c672d0000b8a5d860/0/1: mailbox not selectable yet
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Mailbox Sent Messages: local=00000000000000000000000000000000/0/0, remote=55567b0e54b57d58770d0000b8a5d860/0/1: mailbox not selectable yet
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: brain M: Deleting mailbox 'INBOX' (GUID 58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c): UIDVALIDITY changed (1396487587 -> 1681441643)
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: doveadm-sieve: Iterating Sieve mailbox attributes
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967) initializing
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: include: sieve_global is not set; it is currently not possible to include `:global' scripts.
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using active Sieve script path: /data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/.dovecot.sieve
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using script storage path: /data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/sieve
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using permissions from /data/mail/clientsusername@example.com/sieve: mode=0700 gid=-1
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Relative path to sieve storage in active link: sieve/
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: sync: Synchronization active
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Error: Mailbox INBOX sync: mailbox_delete failed: INBOX can't be deleted.
dsync-local(clientsusername@example.com): Error: Remote command returned error 75: ssh 60.234.77.233 doveadm dsync-server -u clientsusername@example.com dsync-server
```

Despite the "Remote command returned error 75" I know that if I delete the mailbox on the local server and reissue the command it will resync - but this means deleting the clients mailbox on the local server which I'd rather not do, as they can get quite large and bandwidth between the sites is at a bit of a premium.

I also believe that if I do a sync rather then a backup (which I'd prefer not to do, because I'm new to doveadm and I don't want to put the original in jeopardy) there is no error.

I believe the problem likely relates to the fact that the 2 initial lines about INBOX - but I don't understand how its occurred (I've only done syncs of the mailbox - possibly interrupting them, but nothing else), and that is also a bit worrying.

I am using MAILDIR format and I suspect that part of the issue relates to MAILDIR and not being able to delete the INBOX, but I don't understand why it is trying to delete the inbox, and I don't even know what it means by the INBOX as as there is no folder that I can find called "*/INBOX" or "*/.INBOX" or similar on the server or backup.   "Maildir/cur" and "Maildir/new" both exist (and are empty on the client).  Maildir/new has emails in it on the server but is empty on the client.

I initially tried this with my server on Ubuntu 18.04,  Dovecot 1:2.2.33.2-1ubuntu4.8
I then upgraded ONLY the backup box I'm pulling from to run Ubuntu 20.04 with Dovecot 2.3.7.2 - same problem.

Is this a known bug in Dovecot?  Is here a way I can solve this short of deleting mail boxes?

**UPDATES**

doveconf mail_location is set to mail_location = maildir:/data/mail/%u/Maildir   (Which looks like what I would expect).  I could not find any config information with the word "namespace"

When I do

```
 doveadm mailbox status -u clientusername@example.com all INBOX
```

I get different results on the client and server.  On the mail server I get

```
 INBOX messages=524 recent=0 uidnext=60920 uidvalidity=1396487587 unseen=2 highestmodseq=59948 vsize=77692641 guid=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c firstsaved=1680336216
```

On the backup I get

```
  INBOX messages=0 recent=0 uidnext=2 uidvalidity=1681441643 unseen=0 highestmodseq=3 vsize=0 guid=58eedf276bc33864df08000079bc729c firstsaved=18446744073709551615
```

In each of the offending mail directories, "MAILDIR/cur -s empty on the backup version, while there is data in the version on the server.

When I tried to copy the "cur" mailbox from the mailserver to the backup and then run "doveadm mailbox status -u clientusername@example.com all INBOX"  the number of messages returned to 524, but as soon as I tryed to backup the box the error reappeared and there were 0 messages in the INBOX on the backup server.

Playing around with the command "doveadm force-resync -u clientusername@example.com INBOX" on the mail server and backup (after repopulating Maildir/cur on the backup via scp) did not help.

Comment: There are a few *interesting* ways to configure Dovecot IMAP namespaces to work around clients being a bit funny about the folder structure. I wonder if the layout (sans subdirectory) of your destination has an impact on your ability to deal with a recreated main inbox.. try dumping with `doveconf` - interesting bits should be in mail_location and namespace{} blocks - and `doveadm mailbox status`.

Comment: @anx Thank you for this.  It has not  solved my problem but was incredibly useful.  I've updated my post post with where I am up to now thanks to your insight.